# How to detect which button is clicked on built-in UIAlertViewController alerts like Location permission alert in iOS10?

Tags: delegates, swift3, ios10

Ok as I know this function:

```
func alertView(_ alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAt buttonIndex: Int) {
}
```

is depreciated now, then how can I detect which button is pressed by the user on built-in alerts of iOS SDK, like the alert that appear to ask permissions, in my case I want to detect Location Permission Alert's clicked button index?
see the screenshot below.

[image]

I don't want solution like these delegates:

```
didUpdateLocations
didFailWithError
```

I just want replacement of

```
clickedButtonAt
```

to detect (iOS SDK generated alerts) button actions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple replacement for `clickedButtAt`. It doesn't work that way. You don't do it like you do with `UIAlertController`. You have to use all of the proper `CLLocationManager` methods and delegates.

First, create an instance of `CLLocationManager` and set its `delegate`. Then check the current authorization status using the `authorizationStatus()` method. If the result is `notDetermined` then you call the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` method.

You find out what choice the user made by implementing the associated `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:)`. This will tell you whether the user chose to allow or deny access.